# Regex is not working in C#

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have written a RegEx for password which takes any character with min length of 5 and maximum length of 30.

I've tried the following expression:

```
(\S){5,30}
```

but it also accepts passwords with more than 30 characters. How can I make sure it doesn't match such passwords?

Comment: Show sample input and explain what isn't matched that you expect to be matched. Saying something is "not working" is very vague - you need to be much more explicit.

Comment: I tried an input password which is more than 30 characters and it is not validating correctly.

Comment: You might want to anchor that RE…

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is that your regex also matches substrings of your input.

`\S{5}` (or `(\S){5}`) matches `12345` in the string `1234567890`.

So you need to anchor your regex:

```
^\S{5,30}$
```

validates a 5-30 character, non-whitespace string. The parentheses around `\S` are useless and unnecessary.

At any rate, why would you impose a length restriction on a password? And why wouldn't you allow whitespace characters in it? See also [this](http://xkcd.com/936/).

Comment: +1 for the anchors, but I don't think thats the problem why its not working for the OP.

Comment: @stema: Why not? He's using `Regex.IsMatch()` as mentioned in one of the comments. I'm willing to bet all rep points I earned today that missing anchors are the problem.

Comment: OK, I overlooked that comment

Comment: +1 for the correct answer, a good explanation, mentioning that the parentheses are unnecessary, and pointing out that password restrictions aren't a good idea. Wish I could give you more than +1 for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want "any character" use the period (`.`) instead of `\S`.

Comment: He wants to match strings without spaces in them. "." will catch those.

Comment: Perhaps, but he did say "any character" and did not specify non-whitespace in the description (though implied with the "\S").  In general, passwords could accept spaces.

Comment: @Box: You're right. +1 for this (even though it's peripheral to the problem).

Comment: This should really be a comment. It doesn't address the OP's problem, it only clarifies some minor semantics of the question. The choice of `\S` instead of `.` was quite possibly intentional, even if blocking whitespace in passwords is a bad idea.